# AWS Multiple EBS Volumes

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I am learning aws systems, in walk thru they are attaching multiple volumes of a EBS to a EC2 instance. What purpose is it to have these multiple ebs volumes?

Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another side benefit of using multiple EBS volumes (gp2) is that you can increase the aggregate burst performance. Each EBS volume will give upto 5.4 Million IO credits, which may work well for some applications.

Answer (score 4):

You can use multiple EBS volumes in much the same way you can use multiple Direct Attached Storage (DAS) drives in any system:

- [to separate logical volumes for containment](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/alloc-disk.html)
- to increase overall capacity
- [to increase overall performance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSPerformance.html)

Also, note, [EBS root volume](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/creating-an-ami-ebs.html) is one of two supported ways to boot your OS. The other being [instance store](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/creating-an-ami-instance-store.html).

Answer (score 0):

Think of each Elastic Block Store (EBS) volume as a storage drive. When you attach it to an instance, you are giving it another drive to save to and read data from.

Answer (score 0):

You can imagine each EBS volume as a harddisk attached in your physical server.
After you have added a new volume to EC2, you have the ability to use it by creating new partition:

```
# fdisk /dev/<new_volume>
```

Formatting to different disk format

```
# mkfs.ext4 /dev/<new_volume>
```